# How to enable data collection in Ubuntu flavours

Tags: 18.04

After the release of 18.04, when I've clean installed Ubuntu 18.04, it informed me about some data it wants to collect about my system which I was ok with.

However, Gnome had some performance problem on my old hardware and I've installed Xubuntu 18.04 then. During installation, it didn't asked me about any data collection. Does that mean they're doing it without my permission? Or Xubuntu didn't included the data-collection part? How to active/inactive data-collection on flavors like Xubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu there is a command line tool called `ubuntu-report`. When run it displays the information that has been collected and asks if you agree to the information being sent or not. I've just checked my Xubuntu installation and `ubuntu-report` is not installed by default so I installed it and when run the command behaves exactly as it does in Ubuntu.

I don't know if Canonical are collecting information for flavour installations or just Ubuntu but it is possible to send it to them by installing `ubuntu-report`.

Install ubuntu-reprt by running-

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-report
```

Then run `ubuntu-report` from terminal, it'll show the information it collected, press y to send the report while connected to internet.

Thanks to  PaulW2U on [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391451) for answering